# Laravel command - ask always returning true?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have this piece of code:

```php
if($this->ask('Is this holiday booked? [y|N]')) {
     $holiday->booked = true;
} else {
     $holiday->booked = false;  
}
```

in a Laravel 5.2 command, but whatever the response it always seems to return true.

I also tried:

```php
if($this->ask('Is this holiday booked? [y|N]') === true) {
    $holiday->booked = true;
} else {
    $holiday->booked = false;  
}
```

But this always enters it into the database as false regardless of if I enter y or n.

It will no doubt be something stupid, but can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: $this->ask('Is this holiday booked? [y|N]') does not return a boolean (because when you check with triple equality sign, it returns false). I assume the problem is somewhere in the 'ask' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
if(!$this->confirm('Is this holiday booked? [y|N]'), false) {
    $holiday->booked = false;
} else {
    $holiday->booked = true;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to pass `false` as the second argument since that is the default.

Comment: This could be simplified to `$holiday->booked = $this->confirm('Is this holiday booked? [y|N]'), false);`

Answer (score 0):

Or Try This :) :

```
$input = $this->ask('Is this holiday booked? [y|n]');

  if($input == 'y' || $input == 'Y') {
      $holiday->booked = true;
  } 
  elseif($input == 'n' || $input == 'N') {
    $holiday->booked = false;
  }
   else {
    $this->error("wrong input"); 
  }
```